# Where is the composition root for a class library's internal classes?

Tags: libraries, dependency-management

How do we manage dependency injection in class libraries? Given the following class structure, we would like to inject an instance of `Bar` into `Foo`, and we would rather not make this the client's responsibility.

```
namespace MyLibrary {

    export class Foo {

        private readonly bar: Internal.Bar;

        constructor(bar: Internal.Bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }
}

namespace Internal { 

    export class Bar { }
}
```

If there were a framework that managed dependency injection, then we would rely on that framework to provide an instance of `Bar`. If there were a main method, then we would new up all the dependencies there. In the case of a class library, though, where do we instantiate `Bar`?

In other words, where do we put the composition root of a class library?

Comment: Presumably `Foo`, if clients of your library don't understand `Bar`. If you want to inject `Bar` into `Foo` then you can provide a factory method for clients to use that instantiates both.

Answer (score 1):

The composition root would be anywhere you started using the classes in your library from the calling application through dependency injection.